# I want to collect all the subjects that have same predicate and object from RDF file

Tags: python, graph, rdf

I have an RDF file with format n3. I want to read the file and check if the predicate and object of the subjects are same I want to store those subjects in one list.

This is my RDF file

```
@prefix om-owl:  <http://knoesis.wright.edu/ssw/ont/sensor-observation.owl#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix sens-obs:  <http://knoesis.wright.edu/ssw/> .
@prefix owl-time:  <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix weather:  <http://knoesis.wright.edu/ssw/ont/weather.owl#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

sens-obs:Observation_AirTemperature_4UT01_2003_3_31_22_15_00
      a       weather:TemperatureObservation ;
      om-owl:observedProperty
              weather:_AirTemperature ;
      om-owl:procedure sens-obs:System_4UT01 ;
      om-owl:result sens-obs:MeasureData_AirTemperature_4UT01_2003_3_31_22_15_00 ;
      om-owl:samplingTime sens-obs:Instant_2003_3_31_22_15_01 .

sens-obs:Observation_AirTemperature_4UT01_2003_3_31_22_15_01
      a       weather:TemperatureObservation ;
      om-owl:observedProperty
              weather:_AirTemperature ;
      om-owl:procedure sens-obs:System_4UT01 ;
      om-owl:result sens-obs:MeasureData_AirTemperature_4UT01_2003_3_31_22_15_01 ;
      om-owl:samplingTime sens-obs:Instant_2003_3_31_22_15_01 .

sens-obs:Observation_AirTemperature_4UT01_2003_3_31_22_15_02
      a       weather:TemperatureObservation ;
      om-owl:observedProperty
              weather:_AirTemperature ;
      om-owl:procedure sens-obs:System_4UT01 ;
      om-owl:result sens-obs:MeasureData_AirTemperature_4UT01_2003_3_31_22_15_02 ;
      om-owl:samplingTime sens-obs:Instant_2003_3_31_22_15_02 .
```

I am trying to get it but not able to make a logic behind this.

```
for s, p, o in g:      
        subjects_list.append(s)
        properties_list.append(p)
        objects_list.append(o)
```

Comment: for me it sounds like you want to do clustering or even more precise, the find equivalence classes of individuals? So, all individuals with exactly the same features denote one cluster resp. will be returned in the same set and you want to get a set of sets? I mean, in the end you just have to encode all features per individual. How is just a matter of choice. A proper way would be to convert them into feature vectors, and just compare those vectors. Or you could just do it with some loops/recursion and compare each feature.

Comment: Or a more hackish way - analogous to vectors - create a string for each individual and compare those. In the end it doesn't matter, it's just a matter of choice.

Comment: if this is not what you meant, maybe you can describe the expected result of your sample file? Because none of the subjects share the same predicates + objects. So I might be wrong with my explanation above